# How to pass a complex model to an ActionAsPDF?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, rotativa

I am creating an MVC 4 application.  I am using Rotativa to generate pdfs

they have a method called

```
public ActionAsPdf(string action, object routeValues);
```

I am having trouble passing in a complex object to the routeValues

i.e:

I have a viewModel

```
public class FullName
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Index(FullName name)
{
    ViewBag.Message = string.Format("Hello {0} to ASP.NET MVC!", name);
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Test()
{
    var fullname = new FullName();
    fullname.FirstName = "John";
    fullname.Surname = "Smith";

    return new ActionAsPdf("Index", new { name = fullname }) { FileName = "Test.pdf" };
}
```

when I step through, in the `Index` action the name is null... how do I pass the complex model through?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this

```
return new ActionAsPdf("Index", fullname ) { FileName = "Test.pdf" };
```

Comment: how would I pass two viewmodels to an ActionAsPdf?

Answer (score 1):

```
public ActionResult viewForPDFFile(int id)
{
    Data data = new Manager().GetData(id);
    return View(data); // this view content will show in PDF File
}
```

then call it simply

```
return new ActionAsPdf("viewForPDFFile", new { id = id} ) { FileName = String.Format("File_{0}.pdf",id) };
```